# Drupal calendar issues

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am having an issue with completing my event calendar. Everything is in place but the header is all jacked up. For every month, it gives the header as August 1, 2014, September 1, 2014. It is VERY frustrating. I went through everything (the calendar View) and some of the PHP but cannot find anywhere the issue!

[image: Problem]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried looking online and I cannot seem to find the solution anywhere! I even went into the settings for time/date and could not find a single thing.

I want to say that the current date is August 22. I could see if it was August 1 for it to display like that but it is not! I would like it to say AUGUST 2014 or just simply August! Not the WHOLE date typed out.

weekly view:

[image: Working view]

looks fine!

So if anyone out there can please help me fix this issue, I would so much appreciate it! I have been playing around for hours and to no avail! It must be something simple, right?

Thank you!

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I also have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix, the reference to it is here : click on this link and scroll down to item #20 : drupal.org/node/2294973 , however its pasted below just in case that link becomes broken...

Quick workaround for people unable to apply the patch:

STEP 1: Edit date_views/theme/theme.inc and go find line 165.

Change these two lines:

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

To these two lines:

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

Note: the only difference is one underscore character added to each line.

Upload the changed file back to your web server.

STEP 2: Go to (YOUR_WEBSITE)/admin/config/regional/date-time/date-views and click Save. If you get permissions errors, try clearing caches.