# Calendar View of Events shows 1st of month in header

Tags: views, datetime

I would like my Calendar Page View of Events to show "August 2014" (or whatever the current month is) as the heading instead of showing "Friday, August 1, 2014" (see attached pic). Is there a configuration setting for this please? I have looked at various YouTube vids and it shows the date how I want, but I cant seem to figure out how they are doing it? .[image]

Comment: i managed to find a fix , it involves amending a theme.inc file, its a simple change , click on this link and scroll down to item #20 : https://www.drupal.org/node/2294973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix, the reference to it is here : click on this link and scroll down to item #20 : drupal.org/node/2294973 , however its pasted below just in case that link becomes broken...

Quick workaround for people unable to apply the patch:

STEP 1: Edit date_views/theme/theme.inc and go find line 165.

Change these two lines:

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . 'format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

To these two lines:

```
$format_with_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_with_year', 'l, F j, Y');
$format_without_year = variable_get('date_views_' . $granularity . '_format_without_year', 'l, F j');
```

Note: the only difference is one underscore character added to each line.

Upload the changed file back to your web server.

STEP 2: Go to (YOUR_WEBSITE)/admin/config/regional/date-time/date-views and click Save. If you get permissions errors, try clearing caches.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thats a good point, I have enhanced my Answer above accordingly. I also found a similar question which I have responded to here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/drupal-calendar-issues/128282#128282 . I'm not sure if you can link the 2 together, thought I would let you know. thanks.